# Azure Table Query Last Inserted Row Key

Tags: azure-storage

I have following scenario

- Website
- Azure Blob Storage (for images)
- Azure Table Storage (for meta informations about images)

though is that
user upload an image and i

- save informations about image to Table Storage with generated RowKey (integer)
- save image to Blob Storage (image name = table RowKey because i need to know what table record belongs to which blob image)

the problem is that i dont know how to get Last inserted RowKey OR last inserted BlobName.

I need separated Tables and Blobs because blobs will moved to another storage but web application still need to read the image informations.

Is this azure infrastructure suitable for my scenario or i have to use some other storage for example DocumentDB which i believe will solve my problems because i can use standard SQL commands ?

Because this is most simple scenario i can thought about i dont want to reject Azure Tables yet. I tried something like

var table = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference("Requests");
                table.CreateIfNotExists();

```
            var query = new TableQuery<RequestEntity>()
                 .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "RequestEntity"))
                 .Max(r => r.RowKey);
            Console.WriteLine(query.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
```

but error i got is

```
TableQuery Generic Type must provide a default parameterless constructor.
```

Ho can i get the max value ? and also problem is that i connect into azure twice, one for getting max id and second to insert new row with new max id.

what do you think ? It is better to try Azure Tables or to swith into DocumentDB or SQL Server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot issue a command like OrderBy to retrieve the last record that was inserted. Albeit it may not be the most elegant way of implementing it, there is a workaround. You can design your partition key and row key in such a way that the most recent record always appears at the top in the query. This blob post has good information (http://blog.smarx.com/posts/using-numbers-as-keys-in-windows-azure) on how to achieve this. You can then use LINQ Queries to get TopN as mentioned in the following article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894039.aspx

Comment: Thank you I just solve this with storage as a file store with GUID file names and SQL tables which has GUID "Foreign key" FileName column. So I can do all standard operations on SQL and if needed read a file.